# How to remove blood in DeathSpank?

Tags: pc, deathspank

Is it possible to remove blood in DeathSpank for PC?

Comment: I'd say you spend the entire game removing blood...

Comment: Daniel has a point. The game's a hack & slay clone with fun elements, so blood and gore is a crucial part of it. I wouldn't expect the game to give the user the option to change the way it is meant to be played.

Comment: @Bora I don't know... I tend to turn it off whenever given the chance. Games obviously meant to be violent have given this option before. Heck, for just one example, look at the Unreal Tournament series. I always have the gore checked off. Even in UT3 where the blood and gore is more lifelike than ever in the series. I prefer to focus on the game more than the chunks of myself or others flying across the screen upon death.

Comment: True. My wife can't stand the sight of gore in games, either. I myself have no problem with body parts flying, as long as they're made of pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the **PC version** of this game, bought via **Steam**.  I checked the menus over several times and there are **no options** to turn off the blood.  Also, I see no configuration options in the game files to turn it off.

Comment: I supposed that was not possible, looking at the menu in game, but maybe I thought there was something hidden in configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean remove blood from the graphics of the game? I haven't played the PC version, but the XBLA version of Death Spank didn't have any such option, so I doubt that the PC version does either.